# Should this be a Tau or a t-bar?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have this mathematical expression that I am confused with.

[image]

"Study the average 
$$ 
\bar{t}=\frac{\sum _{k=1}^n t_k}{n} 
$$
of n=20 interarrival times."

My teacher have t-bar in the expression but I suspect it should be a tau or should it not? What is the english word in mathematical way for this t-bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bar is often used to denote an average, which is what this is.  Why do you have a problem with that?
Why should it be a tau? You could also write 
$$\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n t_k}{n} = \dfrac{\tau_n - \tau_0}{n}$$

Comment: The way I read it, I was missing a coma sign. (since I am not familiar with statistics, that's why I'm taking the course.) "Study the average, t-bar = Sum ....". Thanks!